# Access denied in UAA token verification

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am developing a REST application on cloudfoundry platform and that requires me to use the UAA authentication. My application will be getting the uaa access token from a third party application. So I am using `uaa.token().check()` function of cf java client. But I am getting access denied error:

> ExceptionTranslationFilter: Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler

Can anyone help me? How can I verify the token in this case.Also I checked the uaa logs couldn't find anything valuable there as well.